# How to randomise text in c#?

Tags: c#

I want to make a c# program which generates random numbers, but I can't find how to.
The code I've come up with so far:

```
using System;

namespace DigitalDice
  {
      class Program
      {
        static void Main(string[] args)
       {
          Console.WriteLine("[1]");
      }
   }
}
```

I just need a way to make random words, the example I'm looking for is how to randomise with 2 different outputs, then I can change it to how I like it.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-sharp-random-next-method/

Comment: Search for “MSDN C# Random”. Then used the learned information to search more and/or write an implementation and/or write a focused question of future revalue.

Comment: Then consider that “random words” can be selected as indices out of a given Array (or similar) containing a set of words. A character generator might have a First Name and Last Name list, selecting from each at random and concatenating the result. Madlibs are similar in that certain types of words are allowed in certain places (eg. Noun, Adverb, ..) where each word is selected from the appropriate list. Alternatively, a basic “lorem ipsum”.. https://gist.github.com/dampee/724a30d8f377ceeb05f4 (and many more examples that can be found *by searching*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate Randomize words using below code.

Below code also helps you to define length of the random word.

First, Have a method to return a random word

```
/// <summary>
/// Pass legth of random word you need to generate
/// </summary>
/// <param name="wordLength"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
static string RandomLetter(int wordLength)

{
    string randLetter = " ";
    string randWord = " ";

    string[] letters = new string[26]  { " a", " b", " c", " d", " e", " f", " g", " h", " i", " j", " k", " l", " m", " n",

           " o", " p", " q", " r", " s", " t", " u", " v", " w", " x" , " y", " z"};

    Random rnd = new Random();

    for (int s = 0; s < wordLength; s++)

    {
        //make newrandom to 26
        int newRandomNumber = rnd.Next(1, 26);
        //it finds the letter thas is associated to the number
        randLetter = letters[newRandomNumber];
        randWord += randLetter;
    }
    //it returns word without spaces
    return Regex.Replace(randWord, @"\s+", "");
}
```

Next, Call the above method to get a random word

```
///Main method
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(RandomLetter(5));
}
```

Ref: Code snippet

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program

{
    /// <summary>
    /// Pass legth of random word you need to generate
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="wordLength"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    static string RandomLetter(int wordLength)

    {
        string randLetter = " ";
        string randWord = " ";

        string[] letters = new string[26]  { " a", " b", " c", " d", " e", " f", " g", " h", " i", " j", " k", " l", " m", " n",

               " o", " p", " q", " r", " s", " t", " u", " v", " w", " x" , " y", " z"};

        Random rnd = new Random();

        for (int s = 0; s < wordLength; s++)

        {
            //make newrandom to 26
            int newRandomNumber = rnd.Next(1, 26);
            //it finds the letter thas is associated to the number
            randLetter = letters[newRandomNumber];
            randWord += randLetter;
        }
        //it returns word without spaces
        return Regex.Replace(randWord, @"\s+", "");
    }

    ///Main method
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(RandomLetter(5));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am not sure what you want exactly but if you are looking for
>   **randomizing words**, you can try the following

```
public class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        var res = Randomise("12345");
        Console.WriteLine(res);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static string Randomise(string input)
    {
        string res = string.Empty;
        Random random = new Random();
        while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input)) {
            int num = random.Next(input.Length);
            res += input.Substring(num, 1);
            input = input.Remove(num, 1);
        } 
        return res;
    }
}
```